# How do I install a libstdc++ that I just built as part of gcc?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, libstdc++

I built and installed gcc 4.8.2 on my system a few months ago. Today I used it to compile a program that uses the C++11 thread library, and when I ran it, it complained that the proper version of libstdc++ could not be found. So I went back into the gcc 4.8.2 source tree and manually copied `libstdc++-6.0.18` into the appropriate location. After that, the program worked properly.

It puzzles me that it wasn't automatically installed when I installed gcc. Is there any way to have it installed without copying the file manually?

Edit in response to comments:
Error message:

```
./a.out: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.19' not found (required by ./a.out)
```

Output of `g++ -v`:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: ./configure --program-suffix=-4.8.2
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (GCC)
```

Comment: Show your error message. I'm guessing it was from ld.so. Also show the output of g++ -v.

Comment: @user3521733 Just to clarify, manually copying the library worked, but I'm wondering whether this was what I was supposed to do.

Comment: Sorry, I mean not just -v standalone, but -v during the compile. Anyway, the problem is your runpath. I'll use an "answer" rather than a comment to make formatting easier, though.

Comment: This is a FAQ: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.how_to_set_paths

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the runpath/rpath. Basically, there are two paths used during linking, since linking occurs in two phases (usually). The first phase is during building the executable, and is more of a "pre-link". The library path there is usually set when you install gcc, and you can see that with -v as an -L option to the linker (collect2 usually). At run-time, the actual link proper is done. The path for that set differently, and is not set by the install.

Probably the best way to set that one is with `ldconfig`, see [here](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig). You can set your `LD_RUN_PATH` environment variable when compiling. To see what libraries would be used at runtime, use the ldd command.

ADDENDUM: Personally, I install everything not managed with a package manager into a separate directory all by itself. I then use something like `stow` to create symlinks from `/usr/local/bin`, etc. Otherwise, things are scattered everywhere in `/usr/local`, and just create a mess.

Comment: I understand how to tell `ld.so` where to look. My question is whether installing gcc (*i.e.*, running `make install` on the source tree) is supposed to copy the newly built libstdc++ onto my system. Because I don't think it did.

Comment: Well, it did, literally speaking. The install location looks like it was `/usr/local`. You'll be able to see definitively where it installed to by compiling with -v. You need to ld.so to look there. Note that you can control the install location with --prefix option to configure.

Answer (score 0):

> Today I used it to compile a program that uses the C++11 thread library, and when I ran it, it complained that the proper version of libstdc++ could not be found.

See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.how_to_set_paths and the section of the manual it links to.

> So I went back into the gcc 4.8.2 source tree and manually copied libstdc++-6.0.18 into the appropriate location. After that, the program worked properly.

I assume by "appropriate location" you mean somewhere under `/usr/lib`. No, that's definitely not what you're supposed to do.  That will cause a problem if you upgrade your system later and the distro's package manager tries to install GCC 4.8.2, because it will clash with the file you put there by hand.

> It puzzles me that it wasn't automatically installed when I installed gcc. Is there any way to have it installed without copying the file manually?

It was installed, to the location you configured GCC to install to. Because you didn't use `--prefix` when configuring GCC it will have installed to `/usr/local` and put the library somewhere under there. You probably have `/usr/local/bin` in your `$PATH` so can find the new `g++` but the run-time linker doesn't know to look in `/usr/local` for shared libraries.

Again, read http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.how_to_set_paths and the manual to understand how to tell the linker how to find the library.